# Can't open Midori

Tags: midori

For my raspberry pi b+ I downloaded Midori (Debian, i386 ) from their webpage. Using

> sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i midori...

I installed it. Now when I try to run it I get an error

> cannot execute binary file

Comment: I'm presuming your OS is raspbian or otherwise debian based (this is unlikely to work otherwise), in which case, why don't you just install it with `apt-get`?

Comment: I don't have access to internet

Comment: If the package you downloaded isn't part of *raspbian* you're out of luck.  Normal Debian has x86 and arm7 ports, but not arm6 (the pi).  Add the output of `file /usr/bin/midori` to confirm that.